# La versión de la dependencia en el fichero Effective POM no se actualiza después de cambiarla en pom.xml

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, maven, log4j

Os pongo en contexto... Tengo un proyecto desarrollado con **Spring Boot 2.0.6**, el cual, por dependencias descarga el paquete **log4j2** en su versión **2.10.0**.

Al ejecutar los tests unitarios a veces (no lo hace siempre) me devuelve la siguiente excepción:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.status.StatusLogger.<clinit>(StatusLogger.java:78)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:60)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$Log4jLog.<clinit>(LogFactory.java:199)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$Log4jDelegate.createLog(LogFactory.java:166)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:109)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:99)
    at com.hpe.clarion.clients.AltairTestsClient.<clinit>(AltairTestsClient.java:52)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.javassist.testclass.JavaAssistTestClassTransformer.restoreOriginalConstructorsAccesses(JavaAssistTestClassTransformer.java:181)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.javassist.testclass.JavaAssistTestClassTransformer.transform(JavaAssistTestClassTransformer.java:66)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.javassist.testclass.JavaAssistTestClassTransformer.transform(JavaAssistTestClassTransformer.java:49)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.support.DefaultMockTransformerChain.transform(DefaultMockTransformerChain.java:43)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.transformClass(MockClassLoader.java:184)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.javassist.JavassistMockClassLoader.defineAndTransformClass(JavassistMockClassLoader.java:102)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:174)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadClassByThisClassLoader(MockClassLoader.java:102)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass1(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:147)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:98)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.findAllFieldsUsingStrategy(WhiteboxImpl.java:521)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.getFieldsAnnotatedWith(WhiteboxImpl.java:2173)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.getFieldsAnnotatedWith(WhiteboxImpl.java:2158)
    at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.getFieldsAnnotatedWith(Whitebox.java:578)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:76)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:298)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:218)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:160)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:134)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:136)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:117)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

He podido averiguar que ésto es debido a un bug que hay en la versión 2.10.0 de log4j2, así que he probado a actualizar a la 2.11.1 en mi pom.xml.

Y ahora viene mi duda... a pesar de que veo que se descarga log4-api-2.11.1 y log4j-to-slf4j-2.11.1 en la carpeta Maven Dependencies, no veo que la versión se actualice en el Effective POM, es decir, sigue apareciendo

```
<log4j2.version>2.10.0</log4j2.version>
```

He comentado la dependencia **spring-boot-starter-logging** de mi pom.xml para que no utilice el log4j de Spring Boot, sino que se descargue el que he indicado explícitamente, pero no consigo que lo haga.

¿Alguna idea de lo que puede estar pasando?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Puedes mirar el "dependency-tree" (en Eclipse aparece de forma gráfica) para ver de dónde sale una determinada librería

Comment: Gracias @SJuan76 !!. Aunque he podido hacer un work-around para solventar el problema original haré lo que me dices para intentar ver de dónde sale esa versión, porque también me he fijado que otros paquetes a los que, supuestamente, estaba haciendo un overriding de la versión en el pom.xml también me está dejando los originales... (o al menos eso muestra el Effective POM) y me he quedado un tanto mosqueado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pesar de que no he podido actualizar la versión de log4j he podido solventar el problema original, es decir, la excepción que me generaba algunas veces al ejecutar los tests unitarios.

Simplemente he añadido la siguiente anotación en la clase de los tests unitarios:

```
@PowerMockIgnore({"org.apache.logging.log4j.*"})
```

Aunque no era lo que estaba preguntando en el hilo, lo pongo aquí por si puede ayudarle a alguien y lo doy por cerrado.

Saludos.